# MySQL Get Min, Max and oldest grouped by

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small project I'm working on and have the following setup:

```
MariaDB [b7_19195200_prices]> select * from watchlist;
+----+-------------+-------+---------------------+--------+
| id | item        | price | recorded            | errors |
+----+-------------+-------+---------------------+--------+
|  3 | 32725999014 | 1.46  | 2016-11-21 20:30:22 |      0 |
|  4 | 32725999014 | 1.93  | 2016-11-21 20:56:21 |      0 |
|  5 | 32725999014 | 2.01  | 2016-11-21 20:56:32 |      0 |
|  6 |      122444 | 22.43 | 2016-11-21 21:03:19 |      0 |
|  7 | 32725999014 | 1.11  | 2016-11-21 21:25:33 |      0 |
+----+-------------+-------+---------------------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So I'd like to get the max of price, the min of price and the first (oldest recorded of that item's price). So I'd get a result like:

```
+----+-------+-------+-------------+----------+
| id | low   | high  | item        | original | 
+----+-------+-------+-------------+----------+
|  6 | 22.43 | 22.43 |      122444 |    12.11 |
|  3 | 1.11  | 2.01  | 32725999014 |    0.51  |
+----+-------+-------+-------------+----------+
```

where low, high and original are the lowest, highest and original prices of the item respectively. A bonus would be to be able to know when it's highest and lowest were. I have been using 2 different queries for getting the highest, lowest and original prices as:

```
SELECT `id`, MIN(`price`) low, MAX(`price`) high, `item`
FROM `watchlist`
GROUP BY `item`;
```

and

```
SELECT `id`, MIN(`recorded`), `price` original, `item`
FROM `watchlist`
GROUP BY item;
```

anyway I can accomplish that?

Thanks!

Comment: Your price data type is DECIMAL, right?

Comment: no it isn't. I put it as varchar

Comment: Ok. Maybe fix that!

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcb16/54810

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't need  the id you can use a join

```
 select t1.*, t2.* 
 from ( 
  SELECT MIN(`price`) low, MAX(`price`) high, `item`
  FROM `watchlist`
  GROUP BY `item`
) t1
left  join (
  SELECT  MIN(`recorded`), `price` original, `item`
  FROM `watchlist`
  GROUP BY item
) t2 on t1.`item` =  t2.`item`
```

otherwise if you need also the id join and tuple on subselect

```
 select t1.*, t2.* 
 from ( 
  SELECT MIN(`price`) low, MAX(`price`) high, `item`
  FROM `watchlist`
  GROUP BY `item`
)  t1
left  join (
  select `id`, `recorded`,  `price`, `item`
  from `watchlist`
  where (  `item`,  `recorded`) in (
        select `item`,  min(`recorded`)
        FROM `watchlist`
        GROUP BY item
  )
) t2 on t1.`item` =  t2.`item`
```

the second should be correct becase select the rows explicatlly and get the first result for non aggregated  valued

Comment: I don't need the id. This one gets an error about `Error in query (1248): Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: @wiZZmnma   answer  updated  .. missing t1 for from ( )

Comment: Golden! Thanks a lot! Accepted